# How to insert Values from dynamically generated text-boxes in placeholder control into database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, textbox

I am generating more than 1 Textbox dynamically on button click event. And also I am restricting the creation of these textbox upto 5 count. But I am not able to trace the value inserted in the dynamically generated Textbox to insert it into database table.
This is what I am doing-

```
<table border="1" width="1000px">
    <tr>
    <td class="style1">Add Text Box: </td>
    <td class="style2">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add More" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" /><br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>      
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button2_Click" />
        <br />
        </td></tr>
    </table>
```

My cs code is-

```
public partial class DynamicTextbox : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    General_Logic g1 = new General_Logic();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int rows = 0;
    List<string> ControlIdList = new List<string>();
    int Counter = 1;
    protected override void LoadViewState(object SavedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(SavedState);
        ControlIdList = (List<string>)ViewState["ControlIdList"];
        foreach (string Id in ControlIdList)
        {
            Counter++;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = Id;
            LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(linebreak);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Counter <= 4)
        {
            Counter++;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "TextBox" + Counter;
            tb.Text = "";
            LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(linebreak);
            ControlIdList.Add(tb.ID);
            ViewState["ControlIdList"] = ControlIdList;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.OnClientClick = null;
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Maximum Entry is 5');</script>");
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = null;
            for (int parcount = 0; parcount == parcount; parcount++)
            {
                s = Request.Form["Textbox" + parcount.ToString()];
                if (s == null)
                {
                    rows = g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_products(product1) values('" + txt1.Text.ToString() + "')");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Label1.Text = s.ToString();
                    Response.Write(s);
                    rows = g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_products(product1,product2,product3,product4,product5) values('" + txt1.Text.ToString() + "','" + s.ToString() + "','" + s.ToString() + "','" + s.ToString() + "','" + s.ToString() + "')");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

After writing this much of code I am able to insert data from only first textbox but not from the dynamically generated textbox. I am getting null value in the database table for the dynamic textbox. Please guide me where I am going wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you running an infinite loop on Button2_Click event??

Comment: @KarthikAMR Yes. Actually I got this suggestion from somewhere while searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **Textbox** in   `s = Request.Form["Textbox" + parcount.ToString()];` to **TextBox** i.e;

```
s = Request.Form["TextBox" + parcount.ToString()];
```

**Reason:**

Becuse you create "TextBox" and retrieving by "Textbox".

After seeing your logic i need to suggest you that you are following complex logic.so if i understood your logic.the below code will help you.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            string s = null;
            int  limit = 4;
            string[] DBvalues = new string[5];

            for (int parcount = 0; parcount <=limit; parcount++)
            {
                s = Request.Form["TextBox" + parcount.ToString()];
                if (parcount == 0)
                {
                    DBvalues[parcount] = txt1.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    DBvalues[parcount] = Request.Form["TextBox" + (parcount + 1).ToString()];
                }


                //}
            }
         //converting null values to any default value.i take NULL  
          for (int i=0; i <= 4;i++ )
            {
                if (DBvalues[i] == null)
                {
                    DBvalues[i] = "NULL";
                }
            }
            rows = g1.ExecDB("insert into tbl_products(product1,product2,product3,product4,product5) values('" + DBvalues[0].ToString() + "','" + DBvalues[1].ToString() + "','" + DBvalues[2].ToString() + "','" + DBvalues[3].ToString() + "','" + DBvalues[4].ToString() + "')");
            Response.Write(DBvalues);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried with this code but now I am getting this error-
System.String[]System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: see my updated answer.you have convert null values into any default values.because converting null to string raise exception.

Comment: do you got the answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Ajay. Now I am able to insert the data from my textbox into my database.

Comment: But I have doubt. After inserting the data I am also getting a text on my screen which says-
System.String[]
But I am able to insert data in my table. From where this text is coming from. Please guide me.

Comment: it is caused by response.write .check your code once where you use response.write() unnecessarly

Comment: I am using only 3 response.write()
Response.Write("<script>alert('Maximum Entry is 5');</script>");//This is for Button1.click.
Response.Write(DBVALUES);
Response.Write("<script>alert('Data Inserted!!!');</script>");

Comment: Response.Write(DBVALUES).i hope this will cause error

Comment: What should I do? How can I eliminate this thing sir?

Comment: comment or remove the line "Response.Write(DBVALUES)".its just showing the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Friend. You helped me a lot for coming up with a solution for this problem. Thanks again. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hello, I am now trying to empty the string I have entered in these textboxes after inserting data into table.
I am doing this by writing
TextBox1.Text=string.empty;
But I am not able to do this for these dynamically created textbox. Please guide me for this.